# Which god does 神様 actually refer to?

Tags: etymology, history, religion

I have the impression that if a Japanese uses the term 神様, they refer to an omnipotent deity very similar to the Abrahamic god. According to my (very limited) knowledge of Shinto and Buddhism, there is no such equivalent in these beliefs, correct me if I'm wrong! So I was wondering if that term or the connection of the term with the concept emerged with Japan getting in contact with Christianity or if it has a different origin?

Comment: I mean, a lot of the time it refers to YHWH, but as far as I know it can apply to *any* god, from Amaterasu to Brahma to Thor.

Comment: Make that _"any god[s]{●}"_, for that matter -- Japanese has no lexical plural in most cases, so any given noun could mean one, or many.

Comment: good point, I was not thinking about that you could actually also refer to all of them at the same time with this word

Comment: Huh, I actually feel like 神様 can only be singular and you need 神様たち for the plural. (Of course 神 by itself can be plural or singular.) Not sure if that's just me...

Comment: @DariusJahandarie, while not definitive without further analysis of the hits, [a Google search for これらの神様](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E3%81%93%E3%82%8C%E3%82%89%E3%81%AE%E7%A5%9E%E6%A7%98%22) suggests that 神様 could be used to indicate the plural.

Comment: Huh, yeah, you're right. 日本の神様 can also obviously be plural. I guess maybe only when it's standalone it needs a little help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Term meaning

#### In general

Any meaning that refers to any singular omnipotent being is likely from Christianity.  Japanese culture has been, so far as we can tell, polytheistic, syncretic, and animistic for the entirety of the historical record, and for as much of prehistory as we can reconstruct from archaeology and other sources.  ***Anything*** can have a *kami*, as the inherent force or "that-ness" of the thing.  As a consequence of this idea, *kami* are generally not regarded as omnipotent.

#### Not just one

Even with regard to Christianity, from every Japanese person I've talked to about this, the general attitude is **not** "the Christian God is the one and only, and I forsake all belief in any other god or spiritual force", but rather, "okay, I'll cover my bases in case Christianity turns out to be right, and try praying to this Christian god *as well*."

*(This may explain why the Mormons seem to make such headway in Japan when kids on their mission report so many converts.  Once the [annual tithe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tithing_settlement) rolls around, a lot of these new Mormons apparently decide it's a bit too expensive, perhaps especially so when compared to the handfuls of loose change that seem to suffice for the local Shinto shrines.)*

This "both / and" idea, rather than the "either / or" dichotomy imposed by the Abrahamic religions, is a large part of the modern Japanese approach to religion in the culture at large.  After birth, one is blessed at a Shinto shrine.  Later, one gets married in a Christian church.  And at death, one has a service and a memorial at a Buddhist temple. It's quite practical, in its way.

## Term origins

#### The pieces

The Japanese term 神様【かみさま】 consists of two parts: 1) 神【かみ】, referring to a "god" or "deity" or even "spirit" in certain contexts, and 2) 様【さま】, an honorific suffix.  Both terms have long histories in the Japanese language, with roots tracing back to the very first long-form Japanese texts from the 700s.

#### The whole

<s>Digging around in the University of Virginia's online corpus of Japanese works, [a search for the term 神様](http://jti.lib.virginia.edu/etcbin/ot2www-japanese?specfile=%2Fweb%2Fdata%2Fjapanese%2Fsearch%2Fjapanese.o2w&lang=en&query=%BF%C0%CD%CD&relate=near&amt=40&query2=&docs=TEI2&auth=&title=&sample=1-100&grouping=work) finds hits in [*The Tale of Genji*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tale_of_Genji) from the early 1000s, often considered to be one of the world's first novels.</s>

<s>⇒ Given that this first quoted use (that I can find in a quick search; older ones might be out there) pre-dates any Christian influence on Japanese culture by roughly 500+ years, we can say pretty definitively that this term 神様【かみさま】 was not coined in response to Christianity.</s>

**⇑** As Aeon Akechi noted in the comments, I failed to notice that the *Genji* hits at the UVA site were for a modernized version.  Searching through the digitized-but-otherwise-mostly-unaltered text [available at Wikisource](https://ja.wikisource.org/wiki/%E6%BA%90%E6%B0%8F%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E) revealed no instances of 神様【かみさま】 or various alternative spellings.

After further research into the specific sense development of 様【さま】, I found that the honorific usage was an extension of an older meaning of "facing, direction", used later as a polite form of indirection to indicate a person, and from that we got the honorific suffix usage appearing in the 1300s.  This gradually replaced older 殿【どの】, in turn from regular noun *tono* "lord", which sense grew from earlier "estate, mansion" to indicate the person living in such a grand house.  This kind of polite indirection gradually shifting to honorific or even pronoun usage is quite common through Japanese history; for that matter, the common term *anata* as a basic-politeness term for "you" originally meant "that thing or person in that direction way over there".

In the oldest texts, the common honorific for *kami* wasn't a suffix, but rather the prefix 御【み】, and we can find lots of ancient examples of combinations like 御神【みかみ】 and 大御神【おおみかみ】.  However, we don't find any instances of 神殿【かみどの】 where the 殿【どの】 is an honorific -- instead, the *dono* here still has the "mansion" meaning, and *kamidono* is a rare and now-archaic reading for modern term 神殿【しんでん】, which refers to a shrine.

I can't get a solid date on the first appearance of 神様【かみさま】.  I've gone through what I think are all of the digitally-searchable texts categorized as "middle ages" (中世, roughly 1100 up through 1600) over at [the Japanese Wikisource](https://ja.wikisource.org/wiki/%E3%82%AB%E3%83%86%E3%82%B4%E3%83%AA:%E4%B8%AD%E4%B8%96_(%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC)), and found no instances of any spelling of 神様【かみさま】, even unlikely alternative spellings (神様・神状・神方・神さま・神ざま・かみさま・かみざま).

#### Tentative (revised) conclusion on the origin of 神様【かみさま】

Considering the following:

1. 神様【かみさま】 doesn't appear in any of the "middle ages" Japanese works that I've searched
2. the existing 御神【みかみ】 honorific reference to *kami* may have been regarded as archaic, and/or too specific to local belief and likely viewed as "heathen" by the Portuguese
3. 様【さま】 was likely in common use as an honorific suffix around the time that the Portuguese were actively translating Christian texts into Japanese

... it certainly seems within the realm of possibility that the specific construction 神様【かみさま】 was coined in relation to Christianity.  However, I cannot find anything conclusive at this point.

*Note:* In modern usage, as pointed out in the comments earlier, this term can refer to any god or gods, big or small, of whatever tradition.

---

Please comment if the above does not address your question.

Comment: Look a little closer. That's a modernized version of The Tale of Genji.

Comment: @AeonAkechi, gah!  Thank you.  The consequences of moving too fast.  I'll see if I can't find a more valid citation.

Comment: When was the Bible first translated? I remember reading somewhere that’s when “kami” was selected among candidates as translation for “God”

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky, what other candidate terms would there have been?

Comment: Alas I don’t remember the details, but I imagine they could have been thinking about stuff like 天王, dunno.

Comment: The Portuguese first arrived in Japan in 1543. Considering the time needed to learn a language well enough to translate, the earliest possible attempt couldn't have been before, say, 1544. The 1603 _Nippo Jisho_ records the word _Cami_ as seen [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=TFJAAQAAMAAJ&vq=Cami&pg=PP80#v=onepage&q=Cami&f=false) (left-hand column, second highlighted entry from the bottom) with the definition, _"que venerão os gentios de Iapão"_ ("that is venerated by the gentiles [heathens] of Japan"). This could suggest that the _-sama_ was added to differentiate the Christian god.